# Assigning Event handlers in DOM

Tags: php, html, dom

I am Creating an element dynamically in PHP with DOM.
I am successfully able to create the element,create attributes however I am wondering if I can assign event handlers in this.

for example I want to assign `onmouseover="function"` to the element.then is there any way to do this?

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0'); //Create new document with specified version number

$a = $dom->createElement('a',$row['sname']); //Create new a tag
$dom->appendChild($a); //Add the a tag to document

$class = $dom->createAttribute('class'); //Create the new attribute 'type'
$class->value = 'button';
$a->appendChild($class);

$href = $dom->createAttribute('href'); //Create the new attribute 'type'
$href->value = '#';
$a->appendChild($href);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And why don't you add the event the same way you add the class attribute? Essentially `onmouseover` is yet another attribute.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0'); //Create new document with specified version number

$a = $dom->createElement('a',$row['sname']); //Create new a tag
$dom->appendChild($a); //Add the a tag to document

$class = $dom->createAttribute('class'); //Create the new attribute 'type'
$class->value = 'button';
$a->appendChild($class);

$event = $dom->createAttribute('onmouseover'); //Create the new attribute 'type'
$event->value = 'my function';
$a->appendChild($event);

$href = $dom->createAttribute('href'); //Create the new attribute 'type'
$href->value = '#';
$a->appendChild($href);
```

[**Live DEMO**](https://eval.in/135739)

OUTPUT:

```
<a class="button" onmouseover="my function" href="#">test</a>
```